# How to send query parameters through $.post method?

Tags: jquery, api, http-headers, .post

I have an issue how to send my JSON string to $.post call. Since $.post default ContentType is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but my server accepts only application/json header

The reason why I need help in $.post call is I want fast end result

Here my sample code for reference :

```js
var jqxhr = $.post(url, sendData, function(data) {

    console.log(data);
  })
  .done(function() {

  })
  .fail(function(data) {
    console.log("Failed");
    console.log(data);
  })
  .always(function() {

  });

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {

});

var obj = {
  "timeout": "5s",
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "demo",
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": request,
          "type": "phrase",
          "operator": "and",
          "fields": ["name"]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {

        "highlight": {
          "fields": {
            "name": {},
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

var sendData = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: include with url

Comment: check my parameters

Comment: try https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: not working bro :(

Comment: just pass the `obj` as second argument or try with `$.ajax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $.post is a shorthand Ajax function

You can use [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) directly

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: sendData  // JSON string
});
```

**OR** use [`$.ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

> Sets default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is not
>   recommended.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  contentType: 'application/json',
});

$.post(url, sendData, function(data) {

});
```

**Note:** `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks is [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) in jQuery 1.8